# SQL taking time for execution

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

```
Select pinv.pipeline_ref_id  Invoice_No,
 pinv.orig_company_id Company,
 pinv.orig_terminal_id Terminal,
 phwb.pipeline_ref_id HWB_No,
 ih.transport_mode Trans_Mode,
 ih.import_export_ind Business_Type,
 to_date(ms.accounting_date,'dd/mm/yy') BL_Confirm_date,
to_date(sf_get_local(pinv.pipeline_tx_status_date,pinv.status_date_tz_code),'dd/mm/yy') Inv_Void_Date,
 (pinv.pipeline_tx_status_date - ms.accounting_date) BL_Days, ih.billto_name BillTo_Name, ppi.partner_id BillTo_ID,
pinv.last_modified_by Executed_By, ih.oc_invoice_amt Invoice_Amount

From pipeline pinv

JOIN invoice_header ih ON pinv.pipeline_tx_id = ih.pipeline_tx_id
JOIN pipeline_relations prin ON pinv.pipeline_tx_id = prin.pipeline_tx_id 
JOIN pipeline phwb ON prin.rel_pipeline_tx_id = phwb.pipeline_tx_id
JOIN multisegment_status ms ON phwb.pipeline_tx_id = ms.pipeline_tx_id
JOIN pipeline_parties ppi ON ppi.partner_role = 'BT'
Where
(TRUNC(sf_get_local(pinv.pipeline_tx_status_date,pinv.status_date_tz_code)) between to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))
```

I'm new to Oracle.
SQL is taking hours even for the 1 hr data fetch. could you please check what I'm doing wrong.

Also one more thing how exactly it is working:

```
TRUNC(sf_get_local(pinv.pipeline_tx_status_date,pinv.status_date_tz_code)) between to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
```

Thanks,
fuko

Comment: You have a lot of joins in there, and the tables may be large.  Can you tell if you've done any performance tuning yourself already, e.g. adding an index to a column, or changing the layout of the query so that it runs faster?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your prompt response. I have not applied any Indexing and any change in layout. I'm using this SQL in my Crystal reports. Could you please tell me how i can fix it.. Is there any way instead of using using join i can go with some other way

Comment: There is no quick fix here, most likely.  You need to learn about the Oracle explain plan, and how you can use it to tune your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how exactly it is working

`sf_get_local()` is a function in your application, not an Oracle built-in, so you can look at its source to figure out what it does and we can't. However, I would guess it's converting a timestamp in UTC into a local timezone. The `trunc()` removes the time element, so `2018-05-08 15:20:01.542` would become just `2018-05-08`, which seems a bit odd given the operands are expressed in date time formats to the second.

As for why "SQL is taking hours" it's hard for us to tell. Performance diagnosis requires a lot more detail. An explain plan would help. [Find out more.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_genplan.htm#TGSQL272)

Obvious things to look at:

**The `WHERE` clause probably doesn't use an index** (unless you have a function-based index on `pipeline(trunc(sf_get_local(pipeline_tx_status_date,status_date_tz_code))`. The problem is you're filtering on a date range so it's hard for the optimizer to tell when using an index is a good thing. If the range is an hour and you are scanning five years' worth of data then an index is helpful. But not if the range spans a year and you have five years worth of data.

You're looking at an hour of data so maybe you'll get some benefit from building that function based index. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS005).

**This join is actually a CROSS JOIN**:

```
JOIN pipeline_parties ppi ON ppi.partner_role = 'BT'
```

You don't join `pipeline_parties` by an identifier to any of the other tables in the query. This means your result set will be a product of all the other rows with every row in `pipeline_parties` where `partner_role = 'BT'`. Maybe that is just one row, in which case you should be explicit about the CROSS JOIN. Otherwise, returning more data than you need is likely to be another reason why the query takes time.

**Some of your joins look like this**:

```
JOIN multisegment_status ms ON phwb.pipeline_tx_id = ms.pipeline_tx_id
```

But everything drives from `pipeline`. You could help the optimizer make a smarter decision by joining all the child tables to that table:

```
JOIN multisegment_status ms ON pinv.pipeline_tx_id = ms.pipeline_tx_id
```

Note that again you're generating a product here. Unless all those other tables have a one-to-one relationship with `pipeline` you will be generating permutations of all the selected records. Probably this is not what you want.

At this point we must point out that this is your data model and your business rules. You need to understand the logic you're implementing and how the data fits that logic. That means you need to understand the relationship between the tables in your data model.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've put indexes in place to aid the `JOIN`s, the next best place to look is the `WHERE` clause.

Ideally you should not put search columns inside functions.  Putting the search columns inside functions prevents their indexes from being used effectively.  *(Search the net for `SARGable`.)*  For example, the first snippet here can run faster than the second if you have appropriate indexes...

```
WHERE
       myTable.dateColumn >= TRUNC(to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))
   AND myTable.dateColumn <  TRUNC(to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')) + INTERVAL '1' DAY

Vs

WHERE
  TRUNC(myTable.dateColumn) BETWEEN to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
                                AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
```

That still leaves the function call:

```
sf_get_local(pinv.pipeline_tx_status_date,pinv.status_date_tz_code)
```

You should probably put a function based index on that, so that the result of the function call can be indexed.

Then you need to start looking at explain plans.  Identifying which part of the plan is the most expensive and addressing those specific parts.  *(It would even help if you included the explain plan in your question.)*